# Print text to command prompt hangs on Windows until press return key

Tags: python

I have a Python script on Windows which prints text to the cmd prompt every 60 seconds, but sometimes it hangs and doesn't print the text until I press the Return key.

Brief overview:

```
 for i in xrange(10):
      print str(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + "A sentence which is output to the command prompt"
      time.sleep(60)
```

Is this normal?

Edit:

I tried running Python with `-u` (unbuffered mode) and added `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print statement, some print statements cause the script to hang. I noticed this is happening on my Windows VMware & Virtualbox machines, but not a users ESXi Windows box. –

Comment: Note that the `strftime` method will return a string already.

Comment: I tried running Python with -u (unbufferedmode) and added sys.stdout.flush() after each print statement, some print statements cause the script to hang. I noticed this is happening on my Windows VMware & Virtualbox machines, but not a users ESXi Windows box.

Comment: Is it at all possible that your operating system is just cleaning up the python program? Being unresponsive for a minute at a time may give that impression...